# No `Podfile' found in the project directory in Flutter project

Tags: flutter, cocoa, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios

I keep getting a no `Podfile' found in project directory error even though I have a podfile and a podfile.lock. I've run flutter clean, flutter pub get, pod init, flutter build iOS and still get the same error message. I've tried deleting the pod file and then running the command sumo gem install cocoapod, pod install, and then flutter build iOS and still keep running into the same errors.

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change your working directory to ios with:

```
   cd ios
```

and then run whichever pod commands you'd like